# How can I display the asterisk missing in first name and title after I made them mandatory

Tags: account, fields

I want to make "salutation" and "first name" fields mandatory in the account creation form.

I've added validation rules and it works but I can't see the asterisks and it's not intuitive for the users. 
I m looking for a way to make the asterisks visible (like lastname - see screenshot) [image]

PS : I am new in salesforce, could you please help ? 
Thanks.

Comment: Is this custom lightning component?

Comment: You have a validation rule which check if value in entered into that field or not before saving, you need to make that field "Required", that's when you see the asterisk mark. Hope this helps...

Comment: You can make required in page-layout, if its standard UI or quick action

Answer (score -1):

You have a validation rule which check if value in entered into that field or not before saving, you need to make that field "Required", that's when you see the asterisk mark. Hope this helps...

Make the field required in the page layout
OR through code like this below:

`<apex:inputText value="{!Account.Salutation}" required="true" />`